# Migrate an express/mongodb/websockets project to what?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, passport.js

At [Weld](https://www.weld.io) we have been handling our users projects ourselves so far. The setup is a real time application in which the user creates their own content that we save in mongodb via websockets and a Node.js express server. Authentication is handled through passport.js local strategy.

We want to move away from this responsibility and preferrably let a hosted third-party service deal with all the data-storage and syncing between client and server.

What we want is:

- Import/Export our current mongodb database without to much work.
- Authentication with our current passport.js based solution.
- Automatic client/server sync (when a project is modified on the client it should be propagated in real time to the database)

I have been looking at meteor.js and firebase for this and It's just really hard to know which route leads to the least pain. Especially the auth part seems tricky to solve.

Which solution should I go for and what is the step-by-step procedure for it?

Answer (score 2):

The company I work for, [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com/), basically does this as a service. It's free to use for small projects, and you can pay if you plan to use it a lot. Super cheap.

You can either use our:

- [Stormpath passport strategy](https://github.com/stormpath/passport-stormpath), or
- Our [express.js integration](https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/) (which I'd recommend, it's pretty amazing).

Here's how our Express stuff works (it's pretty simple):

```
var express = require('express');
var stormpath = require('express-stormpath');

var app = express();
app.use(stormpath.init(app));

app.listen(3000);
```

The above code is a fully featured express.js app with registration, login, etc. If you run that app, then visit http://localhost:3000/register, you'll see a registration page and be able to actually create user accounts. Bam.

[image: Express-Stormpath Registration Page]

The same is true if you visit the login page (/login) or logout page (/logout).

All of this can obviously be customized as well.

For instance, if you want to enable password reset functionality so that you let users who forget their password reset it, you can do that too! Here's how: https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/product.html#use-password-reset

Want to access the user object and store some data on a user? It's easy, here's an example route:

```
app.use(stormpath.init(app, {
  expandCustomData: true
}));

app.get('/secret', stormpath.loginRequired, function(req, res) {
  req.user.customData.favoriteColor = 'black';
  req.user.customData.save();

  res.send('Hi: ' + req.user.givenName + '! Your favorite color is: ' + req.user.customData.favoriteColor + '!');
});
```

It can also do tons of other stuff:

- API Authentication
- Password Reset
- Social login (facebook, google)
- Account verification
- ...
- Lots more.